# Prove that the modulus of a complex function is 1

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Assuming that both $a$ and $b$ are complex and $| b |<1$, $| a |=1$, I want to prove that $\left|\frac{a-b}{1-a^* b}\right|=1$.

My code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Reduce[Abs[(x + I y - (u + I v))/(1 - Conjugate[x + I y]*(u + I v))] ==
    1 && x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals && 
  u ∈ Reals && v ∈ Reals && Abs[x + I y] == 1 && 
  Abs[u + I v] < 1, {x, y, u, v}]
```

> $\begin{aligned} & \left(x=-1 \& \& y=\theta \& \&-1<u<1 \& \&-\sqrt{1-u^2}<v<\sqrt{1-u^2}\right)|| \\ & \left(-1<x<1 \& \&\left(\left(y=-\sqrt{1-x^2} \& \&-1<u<1 \& \&-\sqrt{1-u^2}<v<\sqrt{1-u^2}\right)||\left(y=\sqrt{1-x^2} \& \&-1<u<1 \& \&-\sqrt{1-u^2}<v<\sqrt{1-u^2}\right)\right)\right)||\left(x=1 \& \& y=\theta \& \&-1<u<1 \& \&-\sqrt{1-u^2}<v<\sqrt{1-u^2}\right)\end{aligned}$

The answer I want is either `True` or some other way to simplify $\left|\frac{a-b}{1-a^* b}\right|$ to 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) and since the known constraints are in terms of [`Abs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html), set [`TargetFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html) to `{Abs, Arg}`

```
Assuming[{Abs[b] < 1 && Abs[a] == 1},
 FullSimplify@
  ComplexExpand[Abs[(a - b)/(1 - Conjugate[a] b)], {a, b}, 
   TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}]]

(* 1 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Simplify[
 ExpandAll@
  ComplexExpand[
   Abs[(x + I y - (u + I v))/(1 - Conjugate[x + I y]*(u + I v))]],
 {a, b, u, v} \[Element] Reals && u^2 + v^2 < 1 && x^2 + y^2 == 1]

(*  1  *)
```

Or:

```
Reduce[
 Implies[
  u^2 + v^2 < 1 && x^2 + y^2 == 1,
  ComplexExpand[
   Abs[(x + I y - (u + I v))/(1 - Conjugate[x + I y](u + I v))]] == 1
  ],
 {}, Reals]

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

It is really somehow unsettling (at least to me) that Mathematica, being inherently adapted to work with complex numbers, requires one to manually write `x + I y` instead of just using complex `a`. One would certainly expect that the following works:

```
FullSimplify[Abs[(a - b)/(1 - Conjugate[a] b)], 
 Abs[b] < 1 && Abs[a] == 1] 
(* Abs[(-a + b)/(-1 + b Conjugate[a])] *)
```

yet it returns practically the same result.

However, it seems that we can somehow trick Mathematica into grinding this expression more thoroughly by constructing a custom `ComplexityFunction` that minimizes the amount of certain "forbidden" functions:

```
FullSimplify[Abs[(a - b)/(1 - Conjugate[a] b)], 
 Abs[b] < 1 && Abs[a] == 1, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, Conjugate[_] | Re[_] | Sign[_], All] &)]
(* 1 *)
```

I got to this particular choice of functions by brute-force trying different combinations. We can look at possible choices more systematically:

```
funcs = {Abs[_], Conjugate[_], Re[_], Sign[_]};
alts = Alternatives @@@ Subsets[funcs];
Table[{FullSimplify[Abs[(a - b)/(1 - Conjugate[a] b)], 
    Abs[b] < 1 && Abs[a] == 1, 
    ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, alt, All] &)], alt}, {alt, alts}] // Grid
```

[image]

It seems that only `Conjugate[_] | Re[_] | Sign[_]` works. One step further, we can combine it also with `LeafCount`:

```
Table[{FullSimplify[Abs[(a - b)/(1 - Conjugate[a] b)], 
    Abs[b] < 1 && Abs[a] == 1, 
    ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 10 Count[#, alt, All] &)], 
   alt}, {alt, alts}] // Grid
```

[image]

Therefore, combining `LeafCount` with the number of `Conjugate`s (weighted more heavily by some small factor) also works:

```
FullSimplify[Abs[(a - b)/(1 - Conjugate[a] b)], 
 Abs[b] < 1 && Abs[a] == 1, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 5 Count[#, Conjugate[_], All] &)]
(* 1 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

b can be any complex  number except $a^*b=1\iff a=b$, assuming, therefore, $a\neq b$:

[image]

Here is a Mathematica verification:

```
a = Cos [t] + I Sin[t];
b= x+ I y;
f= (a -b) / (1 - Conjugate [a]b);
FullSimplify[f Conjugate [f], t\[Element] Reals]
```

yields 1. So square of modulus is 1, modulus is 1.